# Python inline for if : Is there a better way to write this?

Tags: python

While writing some code for web crawling in Python, my requirement is something like:

```
vals = [x.get_text().strip() for x in tds[0].find_all('tr') if len(x.get_text().strip()) > 0]
```

Are the get_text() and strip() methods evaluated twice? Is there a better way to write this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `beautifulsoup` here?

Comment: `if x.get_text().strip()` should be enough

Comment: Yes I am using beautifulsoup (bs4). @PadraicCunningham Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they are evaluated twice. To avoid that, use an actual `for` statement and store the result in a local variable. Better yet, measure both approaches - it might well turn out that calling these methods twice doesn't affect program execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `filter` to remove the empty strings.

```
vals = list(filter(None, [x.get_text().strip() for x in tds[0].find_all('tr')]))
```

Comment: you could replace internal [] with a generator
`vals = list(filter(None, (x.get_text().strip() for x in tds[0].find_all('tr'))))`

Comment: @Cyber I like this one. Also get_text and strip are evaluated once and then checked if None. grep: Thanks, learnt about generators today :)

Comment: Filterless version: `vals = [y for y in (x.get_text().strip() for x in tds[0].find_all('tr')) if y]`.  An aside, I'm not sure why `None` is an accepted argument to `filter` considering it's less explicit than `bool` (`filter(bool, iterable)`).